# Cannot find symbol method "setAppCacheEnabled(boolean) - Ionic capacitor application

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-webview

I am working on an ionic/angular application with Capacitor. I got an email from Google, and then we had to upgrade the Android SDK version to 33 from 32. When I upgraded the `compileSdkVersion` I got an error when building the APK.

```
C:\Users\sanjeewa\Desktop\The link\link\link-client\node_modules\@capacitor\android\capacitor\src\main\java\com\getcapacitor\Bridge.java:421: error: cannot find symbol
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
                ^
  symbol:   method setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)
  location: variable settings of type WebSettings
```

[enter image description here][1]

As the Google docs, that method is removed. Does anyone know how to fix this?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7dTx.png

Comment: You are missing important information. How did you upgrade? what capacitor version is the project on?

Comment: I changed this "compileSdkVersion = 33, targetSdkVersion = 33" from build.gradle file. I am using capacitor 3.2 version

Comment: You cant do it like that. you need to upgrade to capactior 5. Look at the docs on how to do it.

Comment: There is way to get rid of this error temporary:
open file `node_modules/@capacitor/android/capacitor/src/main/java/com/getcapacitor/Bridge.java`
and remove line `settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);`.
as per error line number 421.

Comment: but I suggest you update capacitor to latest version to avoid future issues.

Answer (score 4):

Hi I am late but this will help

Just make a change in ***Bridge.java*** file

Comment line

> settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);

add line

> settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

Answer (score 0):

If you cant update to v5 capacitor, but you can simply in node modules /@capacitor/android/capacitor/src/main/java/com/getcapacitor/Bridge.java remove line with **setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)** and then it should works